# logical diagrammatic question

Tags: pattern

[image: Question]

What is the next pattern? Thanks.
*note that it is not from contest. It is from my friend but answer is not provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an argument to be made for

> B is the correct answer.

First off, we can remove

> A & C from consideration since following the small circle shows it moves clockwise around the corners of the square.  This leaves us with B, D, and E as possible answers since they all feature the circle in the correct position.

As for the orientation, there are

> 4 possibilities, -, /, \, and |.  The pattern at the moment is "/ | | \ \" that is, 1*/ 2*| and 2*\.  A reasonable assumption is that the completion is 3*\.  This yields answer B.

Comment: I was gonna say the same letter answer, just if the circle is on the left side, it's a slanty line, and one the right side is a straight line.

Comment: @DanRussell The only problem with that explanation is that B, D, and E are on the right side (straight line territory), but B is slanted.  Moreover, I don't see any good way of distinguishing which straight or slant you'd want to use since the 1st and 5th image in the given sequence have circles in the same corner, but their slants face different directions.

Comment: Whoops. (Embarrassed.)  Good point!

Comment: @DanRussell Thanks for the edit! I'm something of a stack exchange posting newbie.  Been using it for years to solve networking issues, but still working my way around syntax.

Comment: My pleasure. Puzzling is a bit of a different SE animal, and learning the spoiler markdown is definitely a bit tricky.  That said, nice answer, and welcome to PuzzlingSE!